# python online game using socket library

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I'm making my firs online game in python, I decided to use python because its simplicity using sockets. I need to find a method to coordinate all the existing game objects like players, items, monsters width the server and the client computers.

Method 1:

Make every entity (player, monsters, NPC) to run in its own thread an use its own socket to communicate with the copies in the client computers. For example, if I am a player and attack a monster the monster will send the order to drain health points to its corresponding copie in each computer and the server.

Method 2:

Make one socket handled by the main function, its purpose would be to get the messages sent by the clients and process them and send an answer. For example, A monster has 0 health points so that character should die, it sends a request to the server, the server analyzes the request and sends an answer to all the clients.

---

I haven't finished any of these algorithms because I don't want to make useful code so that is why I am asking which of them is better.

If it is possible I would like you to recommend other methods.

Comment: can you please format your question and some code what you have tried? You wrote everything in one paragraph which looks messy.

Comment: One socket per monster sounds like a terrible idea to me. You probably need to do some experimentation though.

Answer (score 0):

run all the players in threads, and have central threads that monitor game logic, and monster activities. otherwise, if one of your clients disconnects, the whole game crashes